# LinkedIn login in Firebase without use of libraries like passport js

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, linkedin-api

I want to authenticate users with firebase using LinkedIn Signin. All guides I found require use of libraries like passport. Is there a way to achieve this in Cloud functions using POST/GET requests?
My frontend is developed in ReactJS with Firestore Cloud Functions as backend.

I have tried making POST requests using various methods including the use of axios but Firestore Cloud function gives error when I try to make any POST/GET request from inside.